# Date no puede ingresar a la bbdd

Tags: php, mysqli, date

Problema: La fecha de nacimiento, no ingresa a la bbdd. Recorté todo lo posible tanto el código como el formulario y la respuesta que me da cuando quiero ingresar. La realidad es que hay 25 campos. Y varios son fecha, varios son select, otros son combobox, y siempre se detiene en la primer fecha que encuentra.
Lo más extraño es que hice una pagina para cada tipo y su respectiva base de 6 campos, y todos, incluso la fecha ingresan sin problemas.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['bt-021']))
{
    include("99_conn.php");
if($conexion === false){
    die("ERROR: No pudo conectarse. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$ap=$POST['ap'];
$nom=$POST['nom'];
$fen=$POST ['fen'];
$nac=$POST['nac'];
$userac= $_SESSION["98_idusr"];

$sql021 = ("INSERT INTO z_dato_pac (00_apellido, 00_nombres, 00_fenacim, 00_nacional) VALUES ('$ap', '$nom', '$fen', '$nac')");
if(mysqli_query($conexion, $sql021))
{
echo "OK $error $sql021 $ap, $nom, $fen, $nac, $userac";
}else
{
echo "ERROR: $error $sql021 $ap, $nom, $fen, $nac, $userac" . mysqli_error($conexion);
}
?>
```

RESPUESTA DE ERROR
ERROR: INSERT INTO z_dato_pac (00_apellido, 00_nombres, 00_fenacim, 00_nacional) VALUES ('', '', '', '', , '20') ,, , ,20Incorrect date value: '' for column '00_fenacim' at row 1

```
Del formulario HTML
```

```
    <td><input name="nom" type="text" id="nom" form="f021" placeholder="Nombres" title="nom" size="20" maxlength="30"></td>
    <td><input name="ap" type="text" id="nom" form="f021" placeholder="Apellidos" title="ap" size="20" maxlength="30"></td>
    <td>Fe.nac. <input name="fen" type="date" id="fen" form="f021" title="fen"></td>
    <td><input name="nac" type="text" id="nac" form="f021" placeholder="Nacionalidad" title="nac" size="20" maxlength="20"></td>
</tr>
```

CABEZA Y PIE DEL FORM

```
<form method="post" id="f021" title="f021">
    <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="nom" type="text" id="nom" form="f021" placeholder="Nombres" title="nom" size="20" maxlength="30"></td>
            <td><input name="ap" type="text" id="nom" form="f021" placeholder="Apellidos" title="ap" size="20" maxlength="30"></td>
            <td>Fe.nac. <input name="fen" type="date" id="fen" form="f021" title="fen"></td>
            <td><input name="nac" type="text" id="nac" form="f021" placeholder="Nacionalidad" title="nac" size="20" maxlength="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input name="bt-021" type="submit" class="button" id="bt-021" form="f021" formmethod="POST" title="bt_021" value="Registrar"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
        </form>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un var_dump($POST['nac']); y ver que imprime? eso seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: enseguida, unos minutitos por favor

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\wip\02_1cargpac3.php:155:null (justo debajo de la lista de variables) y lo mismo para la linea 165 que es el primer echo

Comment: Bien man, entonces lo que sucede, es que no se estan enviando los datos del formulario de manera correcta. el problema es en el html no en el php

Comment: Como haces la llamada al archivo que inserta en mysql, por ajax, o en el action del formulario?

Comment: en el action del formulario el bt-021 es el Enviar del formulario que se supone envía la consulta sql021

Comment: puedes mostrar el codigo completo del formulario, desde la etiqueta <form> creo que esta enviando datos vacios.

Comment: Ahí lo agregué a la pregunta bajo el título Cabeza y pie del formulario porque no creo que el problema esté en los otros campos o sea útil verlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre tu problema esta acá,

```
$ap=$POST['ap'];
$nom=$POST['nom'];
$fen=$POST ['fen'];
$nac=$POST['nac'];
$userac= $_SESSION["98_idusr"];
```

debe de ser asi, la global $_POST es con guion bajo:

```
$ap=$_POST['ap'];
    $nom=$_POST['nom'];
    $fen=$_POST ['fen'];
    $nac=$_POST['nac'];
```

Comment: Gracias @Aquiles voy a buscar un tomate maduro y me voy a cortar las venas de las muñecas por SA LA ME, gracias, gracias, gracias!

Comment: hahahaha, su buen picadillo de tomate, saludos. me alegra ayudar.